# How to revert a state of a remote git reposity to a given commit?

Tags: git, github

I have branches A and B, both derived from master commit 123.

Then I changed branch A and commit some changes to it. Now branch A is:
123 -> 456

Then I changed branch B and commit other changes to it. Now branch B is:
123 -> 789

I would like to reset branch A to master, so the differences between branch A and B would be just 789. It's ok for me to discard 456.

However, I wouldn't like to have to recreate the branch, as I am doing this to be able to reopen a pull request in github.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can discard your "456 commit" using `git reset --hard`:

```
git checkout A 
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push origin A (needs: -f as in force , if 456 is already pushed to remote)
```